# NSpredicate -search words in any order

Tags: ios, regex, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have CoreData stores an object with one of its attributes field "description" which is a text description. e.g. description = @" Severe head trauma caused by accident";

I would like to find NSPedicate that would search this column in any order and by word not exact phrase, e.g.: if I search for "accident trauma severe", I would like to get the above string.

```
-(void)Fetch(){
.......
NSArray *words = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
req.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"description contains[cd] %@ AND description contains[cd] %@ ...",words[0],words[1],[words[2],...];
.....
//execute fetchRequest
//return NSFetchedResultsController;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
 {
  [self Fetch];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  }
```

The above code kinda works but I would like to use beginwith instead of contains, beginswith doesn't seem to work.
Also, I don't know how many words the user can type in, so its hard to form the predicate above by doing words[0], words[1]...etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split your sentence in tokens (words, or maybe only relevant words) and create different entities of that (like KeyWord). That way your model will have an array of these keywords. You can then do a query to find all of these models that match all of the tokens or at least one (however you want to do the search).

Comment: I don't quite follow. So, right now I have an Object(ID,description,color,age,height...). Description field is what I am interested in searching. Do you mean to build another entity 'KeyWord" to index each word in the description field? This is  9 MB XML file that I go through. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this is what I am suggesting. Any full text engine will create keywords to match certain searches. This will also be way faster than trying to do full text searches on a long string. If however you still want to go with your approach, have a look at NSCompounPredicate to create several different Predicates and merge them using AND or OR